# How to Left Join with Inner Join

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have a tables **users** and **documents** which has a many to many relationship with **document_user** (junction table). But my **documents** table has a column **category_id** that reference to **categories** table. So **categories** has a one to many relationship with documents. See screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

I want to join in my junction table the **category_id** under **documents** table.

This is my code so far.

```
SELECT DU.user_id, DU.document_id, DU.dateReceived FROM document_user DU 
INNER JOIN documents D ON DU.document_id = D.id
INNER JOIN users S ON DU.user_id = S.id;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: just add another `JOIN`

Comment: What IS your actual question? I.e. what are you trying ti achieve?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund I want to join `category_id` to my junction table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another join, as said in the comments:

```
SELECT DU.user_id, DU.document_id, DU.dateReceived, C.category_type
FROM document_user DU
INNER JOIN documents D ON DU.document_id = D.id
INNER JOIN users S ON DU.user_id = S.id
INNER JOIN categories C ON C.id = D.category_id;
```

Comment: Or did you actually mean you only want to retrieve document information for a specific category?

Comment: No this is good. I doesn't matter what category id is it. It matter's what kind of category is it. :)

Comment: How can I join the `username` in the `users` table instead of `user_id`? Thanks!

Comment: Join with what? No other table has a username to join against. Do you perhaps just want to SELECT it?

Comment: I want to join the `username` in the junction table instead of `user_id` is it possible to do this? Because in my table I want to determine who is the user.

Answer (score 0):

Add an inner JOIN  is always matct

```
SELECT DU.user_id, DU.document_id, DU.dateReceived FROM document_user DU 
INNER JOIN documents D ON DU.document_id = D.id
INNER JOIN users S ON DU.user_id = S.id 
INNER JOIN categoris on documents.category_id ) categories.id
```

or left if not

```
SELECT DU.user_id, DU.document_id, DU.dateReceived FROM document_user DU 
INNER JOIN documents D ON DU.document_id = D.id
INNER JOIN users S ON DU.user_id = S.id 
LEFT JOIN categoris on documents.category_id ) categories.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Add D.category_id to select like so:

```
SELECT DU.user_id, DU.document_id, DU.dateReceived, D.category_id FROM
```